# Increment array object duplicate keys by 1 in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my array

```
[ 
  {Product Name: "yafuyafu"},
  {Parameter: "sss"},
  {Description: "uyghik"},
  {Parameter: "some"},
  {Description: "YogaYoga"} 
]
```

The key Parameter and Description appears twice here and I want it to be like this

```
[ 
  {Product Name: "yafuyafu"},
  {Parameter: "sss"},
  {Description: "uyghik"},
  {Parameter1: "some"},
  {Description1: "YogaYoga"},
  {Parameter2: "some"},
  {Description2: "YogaYoga"}
  {Parameter3: "some"},
  {Description3: "YogaYoga"}
]
```

[image]

I populate this Select with the Keys of my array objects

This select would not add the duplicate Parameter and description keys and i believe it is because of the name and besides that i want the user to be able to differentiate them.

Please can someone help me figure this out, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why? They're independent objects. What's the [real problem you're trying to solve](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: I pass keys in a multiselect and it won't allow me select duplicate, so I guess I have to change the keys to be able to select them

Comment: This really looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) and your structure is wrong to start with. As mentioned above , explain your use case in more detail

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this multi-select is? Also, why do you have some/YogaYoga repeated 3 times in the desired result?

Comment: I just added and image to the question and more description to better help you understand what i am trying to do.

Comment: if all else fails you could make your own list with a few lines of code.. https://playcode.io/714522/